# How can I optimize this Postgres query?

Tags: django, postgresql, explain

I have a very slow query that I found in my logs and I don't know how to optimize it with an index.

This is the query and the explain:

```
SELECT
  "myapp_image"."id",
  "myapp_image"."deleted",
  "myapp_image"."title",
  "myapp_image"."subject_type",
  "myapp_image"."data_source",
  "myapp_image"."objects_in_field",
  "myapp_image"."solar_system_main_subject",
  "myapp_image"."description",
  "myapp_image"."link",
  "myapp_image"."link_to_fits",
  "myapp_image"."image_file",
  "myapp_image"."uploaded",
  "myapp_image"."published",
  "myapp_image"."updated",
  "myapp_image"."watermark_text",
  "myapp_image"."watermark",
  "myapp_image"."watermark_position",
  "myapp_image"."watermark_size",
  "myapp_image"."watermark_opacity",
  "myapp_image"."user_id",
  "myapp_image"."plot_is_overlay",
  "myapp_image"."is_wip",
  "myapp_image"."size",
  "myapp_image"."w",
  "myapp_image"."h",
  "myapp_image"."animated",
  "myapp_image"."license",
  "myapp_image"."is_final",
  "myapp_image"."allow_comments",
  "myapp_image"."moderator_decision",
  "myapp_image"."moderated_when",
  "myapp_image"."moderated_by_id",
  "auth_user"."id",
  "auth_user"."password",
  "auth_user"."last_login",
  "auth_user"."is_superuser",
  "auth_user"."username",
  "auth_user"."first_name",
  "auth_user"."last_name",
  "auth_user"."email",
  "auth_user"."is_staff",
  "auth_user"."is_active",
  "auth_user"."date_joined",
  "myapp_userprofile"."id",
  "myapp_userprofile"."deleted",
  "myapp_userprofile"."user_id",
  "myapp_userprofile"."updated",
  "myapp_userprofile"."real_name",
  "myapp_userprofile"."website",
  "myapp_userprofile"."job",
  "myapp_userprofile"."hobbies",
  "myapp_userprofile"."timezone",
  "myapp_userprofile"."about",
  "myapp_userprofile"."premium_counter",
  "myapp_userprofile"."company_name",
  "myapp_userprofile"."company_description",
  "myapp_userprofile"."company_website",
  "myapp_userprofile"."retailer_country",
  "myapp_userprofile"."avatar",
  "myapp_userprofile"."exclude_from_competitions",
  "myapp_userprofile"."default_frontpage_section",
  "myapp_userprofile"."default_gallery_sorting",
  "myapp_userprofile"."default_license",
  "myapp_userprofile"."default_watermark_text",
  "myapp_userprofile"."default_watermark",
  "myapp_userprofile"."default_watermark_size",
  "myapp_userprofile"."default_watermark_position",
  "myapp_userprofile"."default_watermark_opacity",
  "myapp_userprofile"."accept_tos",
  "myapp_userprofile"."receive_important_communications",
  "myapp_userprofile"."receive_newsletter",
  "myapp_userprofile"."receive_marketing_and_commercial_material",
  "myapp_userprofile"."language",
  "myapp_userprofile"."seen_realname",
  "myapp_userprofile"."seen_email_permissions",
  "myapp_userprofile"."signature",
  "myapp_userprofile"."signature_html",
  "myapp_userprofile"."show_signatures",
  "myapp_userprofile"."post_count",
  "myapp_userprofile"."autosubscribe",
  "myapp_userprofile"."receive_forum_emails"
FROM "myapp_image"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_apps_iotd_iotd"
  ON ("myapp_image"."id" = "myapp_apps_iotd_iotd"."image_id")
INNER JOIN "auth_user"
  ON ("myapp_image"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_userprofile"
  ON ("auth_user"."id" = "myapp_userprofile"."user_id")
WHERE ("myapp_image"."is_wip" = FALSE
AND NOT ("myapp_image"."id" IN (SELECT
  U0."id" AS Col1
FROM "myapp_image" U0
LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_apps_iotd_iotdvote" U1
  ON (U0."id" = U1."image_id")
WHERE U1."id" IS NULL)
)
AND "myapp_apps_iotd_iotd"."id" IS NULL
AND "myapp_image"."id" < 372320
AND "myapp_image"."deleted" IS NULL)
ORDER BY "myapp_image"."id" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

QUERY PLAN:

```
 Limit  (cost=36302.74..36302.75 rows=1 width=1143) (actual time=1922.839..1923.002 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=36302.74..36302.75 rows=1 width=1143) (actual time=1922.836..1922.838 rows=1 loops=1)
     Sort Key: myapp_image.id DESC
     Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=17919.42..36302.73 rows=1 width=1143) (actual time=1332.216..1908.796 rows=3102 loops=1)
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=17919.14..36302.40 rows=1 width=453) (actual time=1332.195..1867.675 rows=3102 loops=1)
             ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=17918.85..36302.09 rows=1 width=321) (actual time=1332.164..1815.315 rows=3102 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (myapp_image.id = myapp_apps_iotd_iotd.image_id)
               Filter: (myapp_apps_iotd_iotd.id IS NULL)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 722
               ->  Seq Scan on myapp_image  (cost=17856.32..35882.67 rows=135958 width=321) (actual time=1329.110..1801.409 rows=3824 loops=1)
                 Filter: ((NOT is_wip) AND (deleted IS NULL) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) AND (id < 372320))
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 305733
                 SubPlan 1
                   ->  Gather  (cost=1217.31..17856.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=36.399..680.882 rows=305712 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=217.31..16856.21 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=52.855..536.185 rows=101904 loops=3)
                           Hash Cond: (u0.id = u1.image_id)
                           Filter: (u1.id IS NULL)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 2509
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on myapp_image u0  (cost=0.00..14672.82 rows=128982 width=4) (actual time=0.027..175.375 rows=103186 loops=3)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=123.25..123.25 rows=7525 width=8) (actual time=52.601..52.602 rows=7526 loops=3)
                             Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 358kB
                             ->  Seq Scan on myapp_apps_iotd_iotdvote u1  (cost=0.00..123.25 rows=7525 width=8) (actual time=0.038..33.074 rows=7526 loops=3)
               ->  Hash  (cost=35.57..35.57 rows=2157 width=8) (actual time=3.013..3.015 rows=2157 loops=1)
                 Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 117kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on myapp_apps_iotd_iotd  (cost=0.00..35.57 rows=2157 width=8) (actual time=0.014..1.480 rows=2157 loops=1)
             ->  Index Scan using auth_user_id_pkey on auth_user  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=132) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=3102)
               Index Cond: (id = myapp_image.user_id)
           ->  Index Scan using myapp_userprofile_user_id on myapp_userprofile  (cost=0.29..0.33 rows=1 width=690) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=3102)
             Index Cond: (auth_user.id = user_id)
 Planning time: 1.722 ms
 Execution time: 1925.867 ms
(34 rows)
```

There is a long `Seq Scan` on `myapp_image` and I have tried adding the following index but it made it even slower:

```
create index on myapp_image using btree (is_wip, deleted, id);
```

What could be my optimization strategy?

This query is generated by the Django ORM and at this time I don't know yet what code path made it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on generated query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "myapp_image" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_apps_iotd_iotd" 
  ON ("myapp_image"."id" = "myapp_apps_iotd_iotd"."image_id") 
INNER JOIN "auth_user" 
  ON ("myapp_image"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_userprofile"
  ON ("auth_user"."id" = "myapp_userprofile"."user_id") 
WHERE ("myapp_image"."is_wip" = false 
  AND NOT ("myapp_image"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" AS Col1 
                                  FROM "myapp_image" U0 
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_apps_iotd_iotdvote" U1 
                                    ON (U0."id" = U1."image_id") 
                                  WHERE U1."id" IS NULL)) 
  AND "myapp_apps_iotd_iotd"."id" IS NULL 
  AND "myapp_image"."id" < 372320 
  AND "myapp_image"."deleted" IS NULL) 
ORDER BY "myapp_image"."id" DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

I propose to add index:

```
create index on myapp_image using btree (id, is_wip, deleted);
-- id as a first column
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this does not seem to make a difference.